# What is Connection Address for JIRA in Mule

Tags: mule, jira, mule-studio, jira-rest-java-api, jira-rest-api

I want to integrate Jira with Salesforce by using Mulesoft. I have used Jira Cloud Connectors in mulesoft. that time the Global Element asking 3 things User Name, password, and Connection Address. I am giving User Name and Password of Administration JIRA. It was asking Connection Address. I am giving http://mycompany.jira.com/. It is not accepting. how i can give the connection Address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JIRA connector for Mule documentation](http://mulesoft.github.io/jira-connector/mule/jira-config.html#config):

> **connectionAddress** |
>   The JIRA Server Soap address. It usually looks like
>   `https://<jira server hostname>/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2` or
>   `http://<jira server hostname>/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2`

Comment: Thanks Its Working. but When i create the issue how i can receive the issue from mule.Which component i should use. how can i use this component.

Comment: All the available configuration elements of the JIRA connector are described on the same documentation page: mulesoft.github.io/jira-connector/mule/jira-config.html Also: please accept my answer, since it helped you.

Comment: Thanks Its Working. But this is fine for manual process. But my concept When i create Jira Issue that time mule receive the issue automatically. In Jira I am using REST API. How i can receive REST API Message or Data in mule.

Comment: You are deviating from the current question (connecting to JIRA) and still haven't accepted my answer... I'll give you a hint anyway: you can use `<poll>` to call `jira:get-issues-from-jql-search` regularly.